# How to inject dependencies ( or context ) in redux-sagas

Tags: javascript, design-patterns, dependency-injection, redux, redux-saga

How do I use DI in redux-sagas.  I have the following saga

```
export function* loadUsers() {
  // Want to use something like userService.loadUsers()
}
```

As shown in the above code how do I inject userService into the saga, ideally I would like something like this

```
export function* loadUsers(userService) {
   userService.loadUsers()
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 32):

## How to inject dependencies in redux-sagas ?

> How do I use DI in redux-sagas ?

You can do that with the [Redux saga](https://redux-saga.js.org) API, you have access to [`getContext`](https://redux-saga.js.org/docs/api/#getcontextprop) and [`setContext`](https://redux-saga.js.org/docs/api/#setcontextprops) methods that allow you to manage the context inside your sagas. Let's see how it works !

### Inject your context

When you call [`createSagaMiddleware`](https://redux-saga.js.org/docs/api/#createsagamiddlewareoptions) you can pass a context. Later we will see how to get your context in your sagas

Here is how to inject context in [redux-saga](https://redux-saga.js.org):

```
import { createUserService } from "...";
import createSagaMiddleware from "redux-saga";

const userService = createUserService(...);

const sagaMiddleware = createSagaMiddleware({
    context: {
        userService
    }
});

sagaMiddleware.run(rootSaga);
```

### Get your context

You can import [`getContext`](https://redux-saga.js.org/docs/api/#getcontextprop) from [redux-saga/effects](https://redux-saga.js.org) and then call [`getContext`](https://redux-saga.js.org/docs/api/#getcontextprop) with the key of the context that you want. So you will get `userService` in this case.

```
import { getContext } from "redux-saga/effects";

export function* loadUsersSagas(action) {
    const userService = yield getContext("userService");
    const users = yield userService.loadUsers();
    ...
}
```

### Testing

How we can test a context with [redux-saga](https://redux-saga.js.org)
You can use [redux-saga-test-plan](https://github.com/jfairbank/redux-saga-test-plan). The goal of this library is to test our sagas.

What we want to do ?

- Add mocked context in our tests
- Ensure we try to get the right item in the context

With [`provide`](http://redux-saga-test-plan.jeremyfairbank.com/integration-testing/mocking/static-providers.html) we give `[[getContext("userService"), { loadUsers }]]` that's the mocked context for `userService`.

With [`getContext`](http://redux-saga-test-plan.jeremyfairbank.com/integration-testing/effect-creators.html) we test if we get the right item in the context here: `userService`

```
import { getContext } from "redux-saga-test-plan/matchers";

describe("Load users", () => {
    it("should load mocked users", () => {
      const loadUsers = () => Promise.resolve([johnDoe]);
      const action = createAction(...);

      return expectSaga(loadUsersSagas, action)
        .provide([[getContext("userService"), { loadUsers }]])
        .getContext("userService")
        .call(...)
        .put(...)
        .run();
    });
});
```

I hope my answer help you

Answer (score 0):

```
export function* loadUsers(userService) {
  userService.loadUsers()
}
```

elsewhere:

```
export default function* rootSaga(userService) {
  yield all([
    ...,
    ...,
    loadUsers(userService)
  ]);
}
```

and then:

```
import { createUserService } from "...";
import createSagaMiddleware from "redux-saga";

const userService = createUserService(...);
const sagaMiddleware = createSagaMiddleware();

sagaMiddleware.run(
  rootSaga,
  userService
)
```

Comment: How did you get the action now ?